# Word count for each collaborator in ShareLateX

Tags: sharelatex, word-count

Is it possible to do word counting for each collaborator in ShareLateX?

Comment: you mean like this: "Author A: 200 words, Author B: 151 words", etc.?

Comment: @naphaneal Yes correct